# Using jQuery for responsive design with $(window).width()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, responsive-design, window

I am trying to do responsive jQuery, I understand many people suggest using CSS Media Queries, and I do CSS media queries as much as possible, but the things I can do are very limited, and using just CSS Media Queries and/or Boostrap grids has shown their limitations. I am having trouble using $(window).width(). I HAVE searched online for answers, and come across similar questions, but those didn't do the job.

This is my code:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 480 && $(window).width() < 768) {
   $("html").css("background-color", "red");
} else {
  $("html").css("background-color", "black");
}
```

The issue is that the screen only stays on a black background color, but doesn't change the background to red when I re-adjust the browser width greater than 480px and below 768px.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure you're using the proper selector? Do you mean `$("body").css("background-color", "red");` and `$("body").css("background-color", "black");` instead of `html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to call the proper selector: `body` verus `html`. Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").append("<div class='windowWidth'>Window Width: " + $(window).width() + "px</div>");

  function response() {
    if ($(window).width() > 480 && $(window).width() < 768) {
      $("body").css({
        "background-color": "red",
        color: "black"
      });
    } else {
      $("body").css({
        "background-color": "black",
        color: "white"
      });
    }
  }

  response();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    response();
    $(".windowWidth").html("Window Width: " + $(this).width() + "px");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Paragraph in Body</p>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.